# Why do I see the Program+ prefix when printfn tries to print an object?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have an object of a class that I created, I am printing that object with %A format specifier, I see the typename Program+myclass instead of just myclass ? Why is that?

Someone might say that Program is the namespace, if so then how come I am not able to do the following ?

```
let o = Program+myclass()
```

Here is my full code

```
open System

type myclass() = 
    member val X = 3 with get,set

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let o = myclass()

    o |> printfn "Here is myclass object %A"

    Console.ReadKey()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John correctly explains, the part before `+` in `Program+myclass` is there because your code is compiled to a `Program` module. F# modules are compiled to nested classes and so `myclass` is actually a nested class inside `Program` (which is a static class) and the `+` comes from the standard .NET naming of nested classes.

You can avoid this by putting the class in a namespace (but you'll still need to have the `main` function in a module):

```
namespace MyProgram
open System

type myclass() = 
    member val X = 3 with get,set

module Main =    
  [<EntryPoint>]
  let main argv = 
    let o = myclass()
    o |> printfn "Here is myclass object %A"
    Console.ReadKey()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Now, `myclass` is directly in a namespace (not as a nested class) and so it will print without the `Program+` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

All classes are implicitly put inside a module.

`Program` is just the name of the module that is implicitly created when your program is only a single file.

For example, running the code in fsi will print

```
Here is myclass object FSI_0003+myclass
```

The prefix is just the name of the module.  The compiler then hides this implementation so that you can't use it yourself, but you could if you used reflection.

Comment: "*All classes are implicitly put inside a module.*" Er, no, they can go in namespaces as well.